# woocommerce_new_product action doesn't fire

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, actions

I am trying to run a function every time a new product is added on woocommerce, for so I am using [woocommerce_new_product](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT.html#134) action. For this I add a new action

```
function uniqueNameFunction($id) {
    wp_die("event worked");
}
add_action('woocommerce_new_product', 'uniqueNameFunction', 10, 1);
```

I suspect maybe I do not register it correctly in my plugin, so to make sure I do it right I regenerated a plugin using [this tool](http://plugin.michael-simpson.com/) and add it along with other actions already in the template.

In order to test it I just add a new product using admin UI.

This does not fire, and I have no idea why and how to debug it. Would be nice if someone gives me some ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like

```
function add_this_to_new_products( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    global $post;
    if ( $post->post_type !== 'product' ) return;
    if ( 'publish' !== $new_status or 'publish' === $old_status ) return;
    add_post_meta( $post->ID, 'total_amount', '0', true ); // This is the action to take
}

add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'add_this_to_new_products', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply, this one fires when I open the `add product` UI, but not in the moment products gets added (clicking `publish` button)

Comment: I have update my answer. Please check and let me know if any query

Comment: works! I accepted your answer

Comment: @PratikPatel do you know why "woocommerce_new_product" is not working where by in the documentation stated "woocommerce_new_product" is the proper hook to call.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't fire because there's a issue with this hook.

As stated by the support team on this  -> https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/23610

Looks like it does fire when you puts the product on draft, but most users (like you and me) don't see this way.
Should fires every time a product is created.